# Trying to run protractor tests in parallel

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run a bunch of tests in parallel using protractor.. it seems that I am using all the configs as I should but something isn't right and the tests are running one after the other in the same browser instance.
my .conf file is as follows:

```
// Some protractor configs
 capabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   shardTestFiles: true,
   maxInstance: 2,
},
suites: {
  sitePersonalizationSanity: '../test/e2e/Sanity/*.js',
},
// Other protractor configs
```

I'll be glad to hear if I'm doing anything wrong.. thanks.

Comment: Your configuration looks correct, How many  `.js` files are under `test/e2e/Sanity` folder (not includes `.js` file in its subfolder)

Comment: there are 6 files under  `test/e2e/Sanity` @yong

Comment: it' unreasonable.  One browser should run tests  one by one in A.js, another browser should run tests one by one in B.js.    Did you hope tests of one js file to be executed in parallel or  all js file executed in parallel?

Comment: I'm trying to run 2 browser instances that will run all the .js files, and that each browser will run 1 file at a time. To clarify, I know that I can't run tests of the same .js file in parallel.

Comment: If so, please try different protractor version.  Possible reason i can get now is your protractor version has bug on run in parallel or you not get a complete installing of protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem was only with the spelling.

Use:

```
maxInstances: 2,
```

Instead of:

```
maxInstance: 2,
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be your work around and works fro me. 
you can specify the threads
in multicapabilities just mention like this

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec1.js','specs/spec2.js','specs/spec3.js']
    },
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec4.js',
            'specs/spec5.js',
            'specs/spec6.js',
        ]
    }
```

If you want you can include the maxSessions: 1, count: 1 too .

so that you can restrict the sessions

you can group the similar processing test cases together.

Hope this helps. 
Kindly up-vote or select as correct answer if it works good.